# Autolayout iOS 7

Tags: ios7, ios8, autolayout, iad, ads

I am working on app in which I want to show ads at bottom. I have set the auto layout constraints in storyboard for view. Now I need to show Ads at bottom and once it is shown then move other things above it.[image: Image About view with tableview][image: Constraints for tableview]

I want to reduce height tableview when ads appear at bottom. Please help how to achieve this with current design. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a Height constraint and adjust the size of the constraint to resize the UITableView. You can add a Height constraint in your storyboard

I prefer to set the constraint to the largest possible value and then select Less Than or Equal to allow it to shrink appropriately.

[image]

Next add an IBOutlet and connect it to the height constraint you just created via storyboards.

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tableHeightConstraint;

Now to resize your UITableView, modify your constraint and call needsUpdateConstraints.

self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = 200;

[self.tableView needsUpdateConstraints];

Try this Hope it will help you....